# Hooks for post saving make a post-new.php to load latest post's data

Tags: php, plugin-development, debug

In my plugin I'm using

`add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','filter_blog_post_data');`

for filtering blog data before it gets saved in the database.

However this hook makes `post-new.php` to load latest post's data, like permalink, slug, author.

[image]

[image]

How to get rid of this bug?

**Note:**

I'm using `Wordpress 4.4.13`.

Comment: Please post your code. It's not possible to debug the issue without knowing what you are doing behind the scene.

Comment: if you still need an answer please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what must be causing this. Try replicating your entire filter hook with function in this format:

```
function filter_handler( $data ) {
   // do something with the post data
   return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'filter_handler', '10', 1);
```

Let me know if something happens.

Comment: does it get fixed when you remove the filter hook?

Comment: Yeah it does. And that's what's strange

Comment: Really strange!!! Could you provide the entire function? Also, try clearing the code inside your filter_blog_post_data function and see what happens. Just keep the return statement

Comment: This is the part of my plugin's  __construct: `add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','filter_blog_post_data',10,1);` and this is the `filter_blog_post_data` function: `public function filter_blog_post_data($data){
  return $data;
 }`

Comment: the weirdest thing happening as the code is throwing a fatal error when i add add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','filter_blog_post_data',10,‌1); and works fine when i add add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','filter_blog_post_data');
Can you please try this.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as well, issue persists. I guess it could be due to a Wordpress version, since it's kinda obsolete, but I'm afraid of updating it to the more recent one because site could crash. Anyway, I appreciate your effort in trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The key is what's inside `filter_blog_post_data`. Returned array from this filter is also applying to your new, not saved yet post as well.

```
function wpse_288685_filter_data( $data, $postarray ){

    $data['post_name'] = 'foo-bar';

    return $data;
}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_288685_filter_data', 10, 2);
```

This function will set post slug to `foo-bar` even when your are on `post-new.php` page.